# Magento 2.1.7 - Translating the wrong input messages on creating account

Tags: magento2, frontend, magento-2.1.9, translate

So we have a registration form with the fields Email, Password and Confirm Password as you can see in the picture:

[image: English]

What happens is that the messages which appear once the input has been written keep being showed in English after changing the language to Spanish:

[image: Spanish]

I have modified the: `<vendor>\app\i18n\<module>\es_ES\es_ES.csv` file:

`"Please enter the same value again.","Por favor, ingrese el mismo valor."
"Please enter a valid email address (Ex: johndoe@domain.com).","Por favor, ingrese una dirección de correo electrónico válida. (Ej: johndoe@dominio.com)."
"Minimum length of this field must be equal or greater than %1 symbols. Leading and trailing spaces will be ignored.","La longitud mínima de este campo tiene que ser igual o superior a %1 símbolos. Los espacios iniciales y finales serán ignorados."`

As far as I have understood, about the .csv columns is that if I only write the first 2 (the old translation and the new one), it applies everywhere it finds it. And I did search the sentences in the vendor folder and the email sentence comes from a translation csv but I could only find the other 2 sentences in javascript files.

After changing all this I ran the below commands:

`rm -rf pub/static/*;`
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade; php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy;` `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES;`

I also know and read about that both files:

```
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/en_US.csv
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/i18n/es_ES.csv
```

Don't have priority over(Atleast in my version):

```
app/i18n/...
```

I've read aswell some info about javascript translation but I don't understand it because i don't know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix it parcially, I couldn't do it totally because we don't modify vendor.

You need to modify the javascript libraries and make sure the strings are translatable. Have a look at these:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/3109c8e96bcd08041f558be65a2a4e3d213d22a4

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/f67e5989f5efb36ca331e5cc28ee109961fcb99c#diff-008039a39f72563bcec8459724e505b0

The first one fixes the email and confirm password and the second one in theory fixes the Password Validation.

I got stuck in the Password validation because as I said, I can't modify Magento main folders, I want to overwrite them.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create your module in app/i18n directory

create below directory

app/i18n/ModuleName/es_ES

create **registration.php** file include below code in it.

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
   'moduleName_es_es',
   __DIR__
);
```

create **language.xml** file include below code

[image]

add translate csv file es_ES.csv in above directory

app/i18n/ModuleName/es_ES/es_ES.csv

add translatation in  above file

```
Please enter a valid email.,Bitte geben Sie eine gültige eMail-Adresse ein.,module,Magento_CustomerImportExport
```

run below command to register language pack

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES
```

Comment: I have already done that. Of course I checked again and run the commands in case something was wrong, but it's not working yet.

Comment: have you first removed pub/static and then run above command

Comment: Doesn't work, I have removed pub/static, upgrade and deploy and in case I tried doing the same and flushing after but no difference. Maybe is there any other way to do it through javascript?